# error I'm not sure what to do with. Using face_recognition python module

Tags: python, face-recognition

```
Writing frame 1 / 6218
Writing frame 2 / 6218
Writing frame 3 / 6218
Writing frame 4 / 6218
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/main/Desktop/pypred/src/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in face_encodings
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 214, in <listcomp>
    return [np.array(face_encoder.compute_face_descriptor(face_image, raw_landmark_set, num_jitters)) for raw_landmark_set in raw_landmarks]
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: compute_face_descriptor(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], face: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    2. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vector
    3. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, img: numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8], faces: _dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections, num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors
    4. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], batch_faces: List[_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detections], num_jitters: int = 0, padding: float = 0.25) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectorss
    5. (self: _dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1, batch_img: List[numpy.ndarray[(rows,cols,3),numpy.uint8]], num_jitters: int = 0) -> _dlib_pybind11.vectors

Invoked with: <_dlib_pybind11.face_recognition_model_v1 object at 0x1046a0270>, array([[[40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        ...,
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49]],

       [[40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        ...,
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49]],

       [[40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        [40, 32, 31],
        ...,
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49],
        [61, 91, 49]],

       ...,

       [[17, 30, 16],
        [13, 26, 12],
        [11, 24, 10],
        ...,
        [15, 16,  9],
        [15, 16,  9],
        [15, 16,  9]],

       [[17, 30, 16],
        [13, 26, 12],
        [11, 24, 10],
        ...,
        [15, 16,  9],
        [15, 16,  9],
        [15, 16,  9]],

       [[17, 30, 16],
        [13, 26, 12],
        [11, 24, 10],
        ...,
        [15, 16,  9],
        [15, 16,  9],
        [16, 17, 10]]], dtype=uint8), <_dlib_pybind11.full_object_detection object at 0x10772cf30>, 1`
```

That is the error thrown from the following code.

```
input_movie = cv2.VideoCapture("moneky.mp4")
length = int(input_movie.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output_movie = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 29.97, (1280, 720))

joe_image = fr.load_image_file("joe.png")
lmm_face_encoding = fr.face_encodings(joe_image)[0]

known_faces = [
    lmm_face_encoding
]

face_locations = []
face_encodings = []
face_names = []
frame_number = 0

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = input_movie.read()
    frame_number += 1

    # Quit when the input video file ends
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Find all the faces and face encodings in the current frame of video
    face_locations = fr.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = fr.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in face_encodings:
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        match = fr.compare_faces(known_faces, face_encoding, tolerance=0.50)

        # If you had more than 2 faces, you could make this logic a lot prettier
        # but I kept it simple for the demo
        name = None
        if match[0]:
            name = "joe rogan"

        face_names.append(name)

    # Label the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        if not name:
            continue

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 25), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Write the resulting image to the output video file
    print("Writing frame {} / {}".format(frame_number, length))
    output_movie.write(frame)

# All done!
input_movie.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I know that's a lot to put into. on question. As seen from the error, I will run the file and it will start capturing frames but once it gets to Fram 4 it throws all of that.

Ive been looking for other solutions online but I cannot find any that really help with mine. This code is from the face recognition GitHub repo, in the "facerec_from_video_file.py" https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/facerec_from_video_file.py

Comment: and yes I imported all of the needed modules.

Comment: Did it find any faces in the first 4 frames?  That is, is it possible the 5th frame is the first one where a face was found?

Comment: that's a good Idea. The video I'm testing has an intro in the beginning so that could be a possibility. Let me try cutting the intro out. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question, but it explains why it didn't complain at first -- `face_locations` was empty, so it never went deeper.

Comment: I ended up changing the video and now it won't read any frames at all, and immediately throws the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for me was changing `rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]` to `rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`